# i have two table find out only mismatch id

Tags: sql

table 1:

```
id
1
2
3
5
6
```

table 2:

```
id
2
3
7
```

I want only mismatch `id` from table 1 like my result should be `1,5,6`.

Please help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: you should only use the `NOT IN` subquery . Please see my answer and ask if it needs more clarification

Comment: It's a good idea to always use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN, since NOT EXISTS is "null safe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: the query should be `NOT IN ` and **not** `NOT id IN`

Comment: I had not tried this anytime before . Personally i feel the readability of the query decreases.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it improves the readability, I'm not sure why I always did it the other way...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`

```
select id from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work on mysql:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE NOT ISNULL(table2.id)
```

On mssql you can use `table2.id IS NOT NULL` instead of the `NOT ISNULL(table2.id)` construct

Comment: ISNULL is product specific, and the question has no dbms specified. At least specify which one ISNULL is for.

Comment: Good point, I edited the answer to describe the dbms, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID1 

FROM TABLE_1

WHERE ID1 NOT IN(SELECT ID2 FROM TABLE_2);
```

You need to simply use the `NOT IN` clause in the `WHERE` condition , which will return to you unique IDs matching in `TABLE_1`